# Producer Consumer Separate Classes with common BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

Hoping someone can give some advice regarding the Producer/Consumer Pattern – in particular on how best to achieve a Queue/BlockingCollection which is **COMMON** to all producers/consumer class instances?

Lets Simplify the scenario; Consider I have;

- A single Producer class
- A single single Consumer class.
- A Service
  Class which contains instances of both the Producer and Consumer
  Class. The Service Class simply tells the Producer/Consumer to Start
  and Stop Work.

The producer will populate a BlockingCollection

The consumer will need to read from that very same BlockingCollection

This is all very easy to do as demonstrated in this article;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

This example essentially has the PRODUCER and the CONSUMER within the same class, referencing a Common Queue/BlockingCollection is of course trivial as the reference to the object is to a private member within the same class.

If I separate the Producer and Consumer into separate Classes, then this raises the question of how to have a common BlockingCollection.

Should I make the "Service Class" a Static/Shared Class, create the BlockingCollection in this class and expose it as a friend/public member?

Where should I put the common Queue?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I suggest having a separate class to encapsulate the blocking collection, and another controller class which wires together the producers, the consumers and the encapsulated blocking collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just design your `Producer` and `Consumer` classes to accept the `BlockingCollection` as a constructor parameter.

Then, wherever you instantiate these classes, and perhaps even more than one of each, just make sure to pass in the same instance of the `BlockingCollection` to all producers and consumers.  Once you've done that, there is no need to keep some other external reference to the `BlockingCollection`, unless you need it for something else.  It's enough that each `Producer` and `Consumer` hold a private reference to the same `BlockingCollection` instance.

Basically, it would look something like this:

```
public class Producer {
    private BlockingCollection queue;

    public Producer(BlockingCollection queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    // more code...
}

public class Consumer {
    private BlockingCollection queue;

    public Consumer(BlockingCollection queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    // more code...
}

// The exact design of this class is up to you. This is just an example.
public class ProducerConsumerBuilder {
    public void BuildProducerAndConsumer(out Producer producer, out Consumer consumer) {
        BlockingCollection queue = new BlockingCollection();
        producer = new Producer(queue);
        consumer = new Consumer(queue);

        // No need to save a reference to "queue" here any longer,
        // unless you need it for something else.
        // It's enough that the producer and consumer each
        // hold their own private reference to the same queue.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much.... of course just pass the the object byref and all is good :). Answer Accepted