# Is there a way to simply return a BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, multithreading, blockingcollection

Hello i am trying to create an application that works with streamed data... (so no Ending..Complete....etc)
Due to its nature because the streamed data get a lot of manipulation i use BlockingCollection which works just great...
I have followed the excellent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804145/producer-consumer-separate-classes-with-common-blockingcollection) on SO and i have everything works as they should....but what puzzles me is the fact that i cannot some *simply* just return the BlockingCollection from one class to feed the input
Something like this :

```
class A
{
  public BlockingCollection<SomeThing> getBlockingC()
  {
  .......some code here ........
  return myBlockingCollection;
  }
}
```

And on the classB

```
class B
{
private void consume()
{

 A produce = new A();
var ToConsume = produce.getBlockingC();
}
```

Probably i am missing something but i could just get some clarifications on this it would be most helpful

Comment: Yes you are missing something. You can perfectly create an instance of a `BlockingCollection<T>` somewhere, return it, and use it elsewhere. Are you getting an exception?

Comment: I have searched up and down the whole Internet for a solid example that shows how to implement this...but nothing...only the one post i noted...all the examples show operations on the same class or when the blockingCollection has finished adding elements...but NOT on streaming situations....

Comment: You completely forgot to tell us what goes wrong.  My crystal ball says that you should not return a generic object but `BlockingCollection<Foo>`.

Comment: This is not the issue..<T> is not for generic...the BlockingCollection  would be of any type : String/Int/MyClass....whatever....thanks for pointing out...i will fix it in my question

Answer (score 0):

Well since i didn't got the solution i was seeking i just thought it over and got a solution...you just implement the BlockingCollection as a property

```
class A
{
private static BlockingCollection<> _ABlockingCollection= new BlockingCollection<>();


 public BlockingCollection<> A_BlockingCollection
        {
            get  {
                return _ABlockingCollection;
            }
------ Code that Adds elements to the BlockingCollection ------
A_BlockingCollection.Add(ObjectsForStoring);
---------------------------------------------------
}

class B
{
public B()
{
A produce = new A();
}
public void Consume()
{
--- Code that consumes a Blocking Collection ------
foreach (var ObjectStored in A.A_BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
 **** Consume *****

}
}
```